# Extremums and the derivation of the Euler equation in variational calculus

Tags: calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

So I am trying to understand the connection between *The principle of least action or Hamilton's principle* and variational calculus. In my book, "Analytical Mechanics by Hand and Finch, page 46", it is mentioned that Euler derived the modern form of variational calculus. His attempt was to: "Given a known function $F(y,\frac{dy}{dx}, x)$ of an unknown curve $y(x)$ and its first derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$, find the curve which makes the integral $I(y)$ an extremum:
$$I(y) = \int_{x1}^{x2}{F(y,y',x) dx} \tag{2.1}$$

It is then mentioned that a small variation in the curve $y(x)$ can produce only second-order variations in the integral. Now, I don't understand why would that be the case? How does one reach that conclusion? Is it connected to Taylor series? Also why is that important?

Comment: Could you give the book and page number of that quote?

Comment: @VishnuM I edited my post with the name of the book and the number of equation. The page number is 46.

Comment: Imagine that $I$ is a smooth function of a real variable. If $x_0$ is a minimum or a maximum of $I$, then $I'(x_0)=0$, which means that $I(x_0+h)=I(x_0)+\frac12I''(x_0)h^2+O(h^3)$. This is what is meant by "the small variation $h$ produces a second-order variation in $I$". The same principle holds when $I$ is a more complicated function.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro what about third order, fourth order, etc... terms? Shouldn't those be included?

Comment: @daljit97: Yes, but they are even smaller than second order. The main contribution is the second order one. What is important is that there is no contribution at first order, and that's what your book is trying to say.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro that makes sense, so technically those terms are still there and that sentence is not completely correct (by saying only), right? Also is there a more formal treatment of the subject which shows that the higher order terms do indeed vanish?

Comment: They need not vanish, no matter how formal the treatment.